# Simple Opengl program error

Tags: opengl

I've recently started learning OpenGl through the SuperBible fifth edition, unfortunately got stuck right at the first example they provide.

Here's the code:

```
#include <GLTools.h>
#include <GLShaderManager.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>


GLShaderManager shaderManager;
GLBatch triangleBatch;
void ChangeSize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h);

void ChangeSize(int w, int h){
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
}

void SetupRC(){
    //background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

    GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f};


    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    triangleBatch.End();

}

void RenderScene(void){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLfloat vRed[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vRed);
    triangleBatch.Draw();


    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);


    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
    glutCreateWindow("Triangle");


    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    //
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

    GLenum err=glewInit();

    if(GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
    }

    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the errors:

http://codepad.org/aFSEAJKT

I showed errors at end of the lines in comments.

Comment: which line gives the first error?

Comment: glutCreateWindow("Triangle");//error 1

Comment: it really looks like the opening inverted commas on that line are not working, hence everything after Triangle is interpreted as a string up until you reach the next inverted commas (just before GLEW). Did you copy and paste this code exactly as it is in the editor?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I solved that problem but I get weirder errors now:((

Comment: Are these *compiler* errors or silly, completely ignorable Intellisense errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the errors now are due to the fact that you have not linked to the glew library. Find glew.lib (if you downloaded a binary distribution it should have come with the headers). Edit the properties for the project, select the linker options, and add an additional library directory. Add the location of the glew lib (should be called glew32.lib or similiar). Then in expand the linker tab, and select input, and at the end of additional dependencies add the name of the lib file including extension.